# How to define private getter method in Groovy Bean?

Tags: groovy, javabeans

I used following code.

```
class Bike{
 def manufacturer;

 private getManufacturer(){
  manufacturer
 }

}
```

But I was able invoke getter method from another class.

Answer (score 3):

You can't using the `private` modifier. This is [scheduled for Groovy 2.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-3010) I believe

Related questions:

- [groovy call private method in Java super class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834700/groovy-call-private-method-in-java-super-class/2835263#2835263)
- [Groovy Parent/Child Private Field Access Weirdness With Closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951262/groovy-parent-child-private-field-access-weirdness-with-closure/954219#954219)